# Change location of sass-cache for SASS

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

[From the docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#cache_location-option) I see you can change the location of the cache for SASS.

However, I am not sure of the exact syntax to use.  I have a Zurb Foundation project and with that comes a `config.rb` file.  I assume that is what needs to be updated to change the location of the cached files.

What is the proper setting that needs to be placed into this file to move the cache?  I would like for it to reside at `c:\temp` (I am in a Windows environment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this lines (or add `:cache_path` to your actual `sass_options`):

```
sass_options = {:cache_path => "C:/temp"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "config.rb" add this line:

```
cache_path = "C:/temp/.sass-cache"
```

If you use "C:/temp/" you'll end up with several folders with names based on hash codes. Which can get confusing if you don't know what they are later on.